# Power Query Excel. Read and store variable from worksheet

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm sorry for this poor title but can't formulate correct title at the time.

What is the process:

1. Get message id aka offset from a sheet.
2. Get list of updates from telegram based in this offset.
3. Store last message id which will be used as offset in p.1
4. Process updates.

Offset allows you to fetch updates only received after this offset.
E.g i get 10 messages 1st time and last message id aka offset is 100500. Before 2nd run bot received additional 10 message so there's 20 in total. To not load all of 20 messages (10 of which i already processed) i need to specify offset from 1st run, so API will return only last 10 messages.

PQ is run in Excel.

```
let
    // Offset is number read from table in Excel. Let's say it's 10.
    Offset = 10
    // Returns list of messages as JSON objects.
    Updates = GetUpdates(Offset),
    // This update_id will be used as offset in next query run.
    LastMessageId = List.Last(Updates)[update_id],
    // Map Process function to each item in the list of update JSON objects.

    Map = List.Transform(Updates, each Process(_))
in
    Map
```

The issue is that i need to store/read this offset number each time query is executed AND process updates.

Because of lazy evaluation based on code below i can either output LastMessageId from the query or output result of a Map function.

The question is: how can i do both things store/load LastMessageId from Updates and process those updates.

Thank you.

Comment: Best option is - show your sample data in excel and then show how you wants them to transform in Power BI.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've updated code snipped. Hope it more clear now.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want your query to write/update a value in an Excel file (i.e. have a side effect and persist some information), but as far as I know that's not natively possible. To my knowledge, it's not something that Power Query was intended for or supports. There might be some workarounds like executing some SQL (to save the value back to a database) or sending the value to a web service (using `Web.Contents` and a `PUT`/`POST`/`PATCH` request). If you're using Power BI, it's might be easier to update the Excel file with a supported scripting language (e.g. Python).

Comment: Not exactly. When i get new Updates i also fetch update_Id aka offset and then i need to store it in Excel workbook (this part is fine, query can be loaded a sheet) for next query run. But the issue is that i need both: process updates AND output update_id to sheet.